# How Add customer credit points in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer, payment-methods, customer-attribute, reward-points

I created new payment method using http://mage2gen.com/ using this website. It is working fine. But I need user to buy products when product price is equal to credit points. I'm beginner I hope will get help. Thanks in advance.